# mysql - set ~/.my.cnf location?

Tags: mysql, command-line-interface

Is it possible to specify which .my.cnf file mysql client should use? I have 2 mysql instances running on different ports and want to only need to specify a filename with credentials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As documented under [Command-Line Options that Affect Option-File Handling](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/option-file-options.html):

> When specifying file names, you should avoid the use of the “~” shell metacharacter because it might not be interpreted as you expect.
>
> - [`--defaults-extra-file=file_name`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/option-file-options.html#option_general_defaults-extra-file)
>
>   Read this option file after the global option file but (on Unix) before the user option file. If the file does not exist or is otherwise inaccessible, the program exits with an error. ***`file_name`*** is interpreted relative to the current directory if given as a relative path name rather than a full path name.
> - [`--defaults-file=file_name`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/option-file-options.html#option_general_defaults-file)
>
>   Use only the given option file. If the file does not exist or is otherwise inaccessible, the program exits with an error. ***`file_name`*** is interpreted relative to the current directory if given as a relative path name rather than a full path name.
> - [`--defaults-group-suffix=str`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/option-file-options.html#option_general_defaults-group-suffix)
>
>   If this option is given, the program reads not only its usual option groups, but also groups with the usual names and a suffix of ***`str`***. For example, the [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql.html) client normally reads the `[client]` and `[mysql]` groups. If the [`--defaults-group-suffix=_other`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/option-file-options.html#option_general_defaults-group-suffix) option is given, [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql.html) also reads the `[client_other]` and `[mysql_other]` groups.

Note that "*to work properly, each of these options must be given before other options*".